# Mapping python flask website to a domain name

Tags: python, flask, deployment, cpanel

I have a domain, domain_name.com. On my local machine, a website is made using python flask. In the home directory of the server for domain_name.com, I put all the files in a folder 'school' and in the python3 virtual environment execute the command `./main.py runserver`, which gives:

`* Serving Flask app "memorizer.application" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

How do I map this to domain_name.com/school? The local machine is on ubuntu 18.04 and the server is linux millennium. I have access to the cpanel.

Below is the sequence to run the script on the server:

`. cd school/`

`. ls
app.py     memorizer.db       Pipfile.lock  setup.cfg
LICENSE    migrations         public        tests
main.py    passenger_wsgi.py  questions     tmp
memorizer  Pipfile            README.md     tox.ini`

`. pwd
/home/user_name/school`

`. cat main.py`

`#!/usr/bin/env python3
from memorizer.application import manager
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()`

`. source /home/user_name/virtualenv/school/3.5/bin/activate`

`(school:3.5). ./main.py runserver
 * Serving Flask app "memorizer.application" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

Comment: if you use `127.0.0.1` then you can't access it from any other computer. You have to use `0.0.0.0` on local machine. But it still may need a lot of work. On server you would have to configure to redirect `domain_name.com/school` to external IP of your local machine - it is IP used by router of your internet provider. If you don't have static external IP then you would have to change configuration on server every time when provider will change your external IP. Frankly, it is easier to put flask on server.

Comment: The server has a static external IP. I am running flask in a python3 virtual environment on the server. The code is based on flask.

Comment: I was thinking you want to run flask on local computer and redirect it from server to local computer. But it seems  you want to run code on server. Flask doesn't care where you keep code. If you don't have other web server (nginx, apache) then you can run it in any folder and you have to use `@app.router("/school/...")`. And it needs to use `app.run(host="0.0.0.0")`.

Comment: If you already have nginx/apache as web server then you have to configure it to redirect `domain_name.com/school` to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` - nginx/apache will work as `"proxy server"`. On [Full Stack Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/wsgi-servers.html) you can see example configuration to redirect `nginx` to `wsgi server` which runs flask. It uses `Location /` but you would have to use `Location /school`. I'm not sure if you will have to use also `@app.router("/school/...")` but again flask doesn't care in what folder do you have code.

Comment: There is no nginx/apache on the server and I am not able to install it. Don't know how to install things on linux millennium.

Comment: If you don't have apache/nginx then you can run flask directly - but you have to use `host='0.0.0.0'` and `port=80`. And you have to use  `@app.router("/school/...")` to have urls like `http://domain_name.com/school`. Other thing is if `domain_name.com` is assigned to `IP` of this server.

Comment: where do I specify `host=0.0.0.0` and `port=80`?

Comment: `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80)`

Comment: on using `grep -r app * | grep run` in the `school` folder, I get no results. am I supposed to create a new file? where do I put `./main.py runserver`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201719/discussion-between-jhaprade-and-furas).

Comment: in most tutorials you can see `app = Flask()` and `app.run()`. And most people use name `app`. But maybe you used different name. Maybe in your code it is `manager.run()`. I don't know.

Comment: I am clueless what to do